# How to redeem Origins Edition skins?

Tags: overwatch

I bought the Origins Edition of the game the other day, just wondering about the small set of skins that people are saying had come along (ex: overgrown bastion, strike-commander morrison, etc.), how do I redeem them?

Comment: Have you actually checked in game yet?

Comment: @NathanK I posted this before the game was released.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The skins come with your version of the game. When you install, they should be there automatically. If they don't show up, I would contact Blizzard support.

Comment: Can confirm. If you don't see them in your Hero Gallery, there's an issue of some kind, and contacting support will be your only real option.

Answer (score -1):

there is sometimes a code on the disc packet if u bought disc

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? This does not provide much of an answer.